# Cannot obtain value after filter() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to obtain the value of a filtered array. In debugger, it shows I can find the value in the array, which return only one result, which is desired, after I assigned to another value I got undefined, why is that ?
I have been using it the same way before.

```
let originalpost = raw.filter(a => a.id == id); // one record shown
let topic = originalpost.title;// undefine
```

previously I done this

```
  let data = raw.filter(a => a.ParentItemID == id);// an array of records retrieved

// later I can use its data....
// e.g. data.title ....
```

Comment: `filter` will _always_ return a new array. So you probably want `originalpost[0].title`. Or use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Also, maybe check your spelling. `orignal` or `original`?

Comment: oh thats why. thanks!

Comment: Thanks all, what a silly mistake of me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will always get you an array of objects. For getting only one value you should use [Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Follows an example:

```js
const values = [
    {id:1, name:"first"},
    {id:2, name:"second"}
];

console.log(values.filter(element => element.id === 2));
console.log(values.find(element => element.id === 2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am missing the [0] to get the result of an array :)

Answer (score 0):

.filter returns results in an array, so one result means array starts from 0
thus

```
let originalpost = raw.filter(a => a.id == id); // one record shown
let topic = originalpost[0].title;// undefine
```